# How to select different values in a column with the same ID and then delete them PHP SQL Server

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, where-clause, sql-delete

I am new to the world of programming. I am in need of help in this sentence. what I want to do is select the 0.1,2 values from the CardIndex column and then be able to delete them. Rows must be removed as long as the condition is met. Or what would be the best way to do it.

CardIndex column must have the 3 values yes or yes to execute the delete. otherwise it will not be executed

[image]

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM CardData where UserIndex='$id' and CardIndex in (0,1,2) ";
$resultados = sqlsrv_query($conn,$query);

if($query1 = sqlsrv_fetch_array($resultados)){
        if($query1 == true){
        $cro =  "DELETE FROM CardData WHERE UserIndex='$id' and CardIndex in (0,1,2)";
        $query3 = sqlsrv_query($conn,$cro); 
        }

    echo 'funciona';
    }

    else{
     echo 'no funciona';    

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want `or`, not `and` - otherwise you search for rows whose `CardIndex` has all three values at once, which, obviously, never happens:

```
DELETE FROM CardData 
WHERE 
    UserIndex = @UserIndex
    AND (CardIndex = 1 OR CardIndex = 2 OR CardIndex = 3)
```

This can be shortened with `IN`:

```
DELETE FROM CardData 
WHERE UserIndex = @UserIndex AND CardIndex IN (1, 2, 3)
```

Note that there is no point `SELECT`ing the values before deleting them. You can just fire the `DELETE` directly: if no row matches the condition, no actual deletion will happen.

Finally: do not concatenate variables in the query string; this is inefficient and exposes your code to SQL injection. Instead, you should use parameterized queries (there are plenty of online resources that explain how to this right).

---

**Edit**

You want to delete all three records only if all three `cardIndex` values are available for the given `userIndex`. Assuming that there are no duplicate `(userIndex, cardIndex)`, one method is an updateable CTE:

```
with cte as (
    select count(*) over() cnt
    from cardData
    where userIndex = @UserIndex and cardIndex in (1, 2, 3)
)
delete from cte where cnt = 3
```

Comment: it is true that the in (1,2,3) works
but it is not fulfilling the condition, that CardIndex contains the values 0,1,2 obligatory. If the 3 values do not exist, delete should not be executed. the CardIndex column must have the 3 values yes or yes to execute the delete. otherwise it will not be executed.

Comment: @IchigoKurosaki: ah, ok. It makes more sense then. See my updated answer.

Comment: Doesn't work in php when run :( Warning: sqlsrv_fetch_array () expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in
$ query = "with cte as (SELECT count (*) over () cnt FROM CardData where UserIndex = $id and CardIndex in (1, 2, 3))";

Comment: @IchigoKurosaki: it looks like you forgot a part of the query (the one that starts with `delete`).